# Capacitor Device Plugin works on ionic serve, but not on my phone when testing with Android Studio

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have an issue with the Device plugin from Capacitor. When using Device.getLanguageCode() I get the correct language code when I am testing the application in the browser with ionic serve. However, when I am testing the application on my own phone with android studio, the language code is not retrieved. I tried to print the language code to the screen, but there is nothing coming up.

I suspect that it may be because the app is just in testing-mode, but it is still installed on the phone, so shouldn't it be able to get the device info? Help is much appreciated!

I am using ionic with react.

Code:

```
  /* --------------------- Setting Language --------------------- */
    const { Device } = Plugins;
    const languageCtx = useContext(LanguageContext);

    let fixedLangCode = 0; // 0 is default language code (English).
    Device.getLanguageCode().then((langCode) => {
      if (langCode.value.includes("NO")) {
        fixedLangCode = 1; //1 is Norwegian language code.
      }
      languageCtx.updateLanguageCode(fixedLangCode);
    });
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Error message:
There does not seem to be any error message. The only thing that is mentioned when starting up the application about the getLanguageCode is this:

```
V/Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Capacitor plugin): callbackId: 27212778, pluginId: Device, methodName: getLanguageCode
V/Capacitor: callback: 27212778, pluginId: Device, methodName: getLanguageCode, methodData: {}
```

And the Device plugin is mentioned among all the other plugins like this:

```
D/Capacitor: Registering plugin: Device
```

Comment: Can you post some code samples and the error message you're getting?

Comment: @johnborges I found the solution to my problem, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem and solution. Turns out there was nothing wrong, it was just a difference between the getLanguageCode.value result in the browser and on the phone.

In the browser, the getLanguageCode.value returns "nb-NO".

In the mobile application, the getLanguageCode.value returns "nb".

Since my program was designed to detect "NO" and not "nb" it seemed like it didn't work.